# How can I use placeholders for variadic SQL functions with Perl's DBI?

Tags: sql, perl, dbi

I don't know if "variadic" is actually the right word, but I'm talking about things that can take a list of values, like `IN()`. If you've been working with DBI for long, you've probably tried to do this:

(Note: All examples extremely simplified for brevity)

```
my $vals = join ', ', @numbers;
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( "SELECT * FROM mytbl WHERE foo IN( ? )" );
$sth->execute( $vals );     # doesn't work
```

DBI placeholders simply don't support these kinds of shenanigans, it's a single value for each `?` or nothing, as far as I know.

This leads me to end up doing something like:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( "SELECT * FROM mytbl WHERE foo IN ( $vals )" );
```

which isn't *so* horrible, but consider a function, like one I wrote today, that has to accept some arbitrary SQL with an `IN` clause and a list of values

```
sub example { 
    my $self = shift;
    my ( $sql, @args ) = @_;

    my $vals = join ', ', @args;
    $sql =~ s/XXX/$vals/;    <---- # AARRRGHGH
    my $sth = $self->dbh->prepare( $sql );
    ...
}
```

This ends up getting called by stuff that looks like

```
my $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytbl WHERE foo IN( XXX ) AND bar = 42 ORDER BY baz";
my $result = $self->example( $sql, @quux );
```

This really offends my sense of aesthetics. Building custom SQL programmaticly is a big enough pain as it is; I don't want to go down the road of regexing my SQL strings if I don't have to.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sprintf` is handy in such situations:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( 
    sprintf(
        'SELECT * FROM mytbl WHERE foo IN( %s )',
        join(',', ('?') x @numbers) )
);
```

Comment: I like the `sprintf` idea; I'm amazed I didn't think of that as I was working on this

Comment: I always thought that `sprintf` wasn't very perlish, but there's definitely advantages in complicated substitutions (e.g. my concat statement in comments below is write-only). :)

Comment: Perlish = getting the job done easily. sprintf is often an easy way to get the job done, ergo ... :)

Answer (score 5):

Food for thought.

[DBIx::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~juerd/DBIx-Simple/lib/DBIx/Simple.pm) offers a syntax for this type of thing using a double-question mark placeholder:

```
$db->query( 'SELECT * FROM mytbl WHERE foo IN ( ?? )', @args );
```

Also, [SQL::Abstract](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/SQL-Abstract-1.60/lib/SQL/Abstract.pm) is powerful, but I find sometimes the abstractions don't result in optimal SQL.

Answer (score 5):

Why not:

```
  my $sql = "SELECT * FROM mytbl WHERE foo IN(" . join(',', ('?')x@quux) . ") AND bar = 42 ORDER BY baz";
  my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $sth->execute(@quux);
```

Comment: I wrote just such a method yesterday (well actually it was `my $sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . $databaseName . '.' . $tableName . ' (' . join(', ', $this->_fields) . ')' . ' VALUES (' . join(', ', ('?') x @{$this->_fields}) . ')';`, but close enough :)

Comment: With such a statement, take care that @quux isn't empty... `WHERE foo IN()` isn't valid.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind breaking from pure DBI and using some modules, I'd take a look at [SQL::Abstract](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/SQL-Abstract-1.60/lib/SQL/Abstract.pm) for your example.  [SQL::Abstract](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/SQL-Abstract-1.60/lib/SQL/Abstract.pm) can take a Perl hash and turn it into a [`where` clause](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/SQL-Abstract-1.60/lib/SQL/Abstract.pm#WHERE_CLAUSES).

```
my $sql  = SQL::Abstract->new;
my @numbers = (1 .. 10);
my ($stmt, @bind) = $sql->where({foo => {'in', \@numbers}});
# $stmt is " WHERE ( foo IN ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) )"
# @bind contains the values 1 through 10.
```

Answer (score 2):

If using placeholders and bind values gets clumsy, there's always `DBI::quote()`.

```
my $sql = sprintf 'SELECT * FROM mytabl WHERE foo IN ( %s )',
     join( ',', map { $dbh->quote( $_ ) } @args );
```